# factor analysis for given data with help of matlab

Tags: pca, matlab, factor-analysis

suppose that we have following data

[image]

i have done covariance matrix and  eigenvalue decomposition

```
>> means=mean(X);
>> centered=X-repmat(means,10,1);
>> covariance=(centered'*centered)/(9);

>> [V,D]=eig(covariance);
>> [e,i]=sort(diag(D),'descend');
>> sorted=V(:,i);

e

e =

   1.0e+03 *

    3.8861
    0.4605
    0.1162
    0.0465

>> sorted

sorted =

    0.5080    0.5042    0.3747   -0.5893
    0.0090   -0.6091    0.7930   -0.0092
    0.8560   -0.3490   -0.2747    0.2647
    0.0955    0.5030    0.3941    0.7633
```

i have calculated also percentage distribution

```
(e./sum(e))*100

ans =

   86.1796
   10.2125
    2.5776
    1.0303
```

for instance i want to choose first two,because in sum they have  more then 96% of total variance,now please  how can i continue for factor analysis?matlab commands also visual help will be very good,according to this answer

[Steps done in factor analysis compared to steps done in PCA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102882/steps-done-in-factor-analysis-compared-to-steps-done-in-pca)

i was confused,so please  for given concrete numerical example,how can i continue,not just definitions,i need concrete numerical steps.thansk in advance

EDITED :
because i have choose first two  eigenvector,i have done PCA also

```
factors=sorted(:,1:2)

factors =

    0.5080    0.5042
    0.0090   -0.6091
    0.8560   -0.3490
    0.0955    0.5030

>> PCA=X*factors

PCA =

  299.5739   24.8602
  150.1380   65.5846
  183.9319   36.7606
  156.7749   11.6325
   58.1864   17.0585
  236.6723   35.3584
  176.0291   68.7008
  208.4237   45.3761
  190.6039   33.7278
  206.2131    3.4430
```

how can i calculate loadings?how can i do orthogonal rotations?

Comment: any help?any ideas,but please with concrete answers,i dont need theoretical definitions

Comment: From your question it may seem that you think that factor analysis = PCA + rotation. Do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news! You've allready calculated the loadings. The loadings are the weight each observation gets in the principal components. What you call 'factors' are the 'factor loadings'.

Rotations are performed on these 'loadings'=='eigenvectors'. The method to do this is dependent on the type of (ortoghonal) rotation you intend to do. The `stats` package has `pca()` and [`rotatefactors()` (link)](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/rotatefactors.html) methods it that package is available to you.

Sidenote: I see that you calculated the eigenvectors with the covariance matrix, this assumes that all data is in the same scale. That is variations in Hours have the same impact as variations in Price. It might be more informative to use the eigenvalues of the correlation matrix `corrcoef()`.

I also see that a lot of your coding is "reinventing the wheel" maybe thats intentional to learn but for example covariance matrices are built in in base via [`var(X)` (link)](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/var.html).

Good luck!

Comment: `The loadings are the weight each observation gets in the principal components` What do you mean?

Comment: what I mean is that a matrix $K \times N$ of observations of the variables with rows $X_i =$ `[Sales, Price, Advert., Ass. Hours]`_i (i=1..N) which we're trying to reduce using `PCA` is weighted by loadings (eigenvectors) $V_1 .. V_K$ (each of length $K$) to form principal component $k$ row $i$ according to ${PCA}_{ik}= \sum_{\kappa=1}^K X_{i\kappa} \cdot V_{\kappa k}$. Hope the math is ok :)

Comment: thanks  for your  answer,just i want to see  formula of rotation,what is  rotational matrix in this case

Comment: That's dependant on the type of rotation you would like to perform. As the eigenvectors are by definition orthogonal, every orthogonal rotation matrix will do. Typically this is an optimization. Varimax is fairly standard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varimax_rotation

Comment: ok but that step is very interesting for me,i have got loadings right,no what  i should do?should i multiply this matrix by some orthogonal matrix or?ok simple mathematical formula for it,let say Varimax

Comment: $PC = \text{eigenvector}(\text{cov}(X))$; $R_{Varimax}\cdot PC = RC$; $X\cdot RC$

Comment: sorry what is RC?in this case what is form of Rvarimax?