# R multiple correspondence analysis loadings

Tags: r, pca, correspondence-analysis, biplot

I'm running a multiple correspondence analysis in `R` using the `FactoMineR` package:

```
mca_fit <- MCA(df, ncp = 7, quali.sup=c(1), na.method="Average")
```

I'm trying to get loading values for each item, which I do by running the following (as recommended by the FactoMineR [website](http://factominer.free.fr/faq/index.html)):

```
sweep(mca_fit$var$coord,2,sqrt(mca_fit$eig[1:ncol(mca_fit$var$coord),1]),FUN="/")
```

However, I get some rather large loading values (e.g. `-2.089`, `-1.867`):

```
             Dim 1         Dim 2        Dim 3        Dim 4        Dim 5       Dim 6         Dim 7
q3_1  -0.067258071  0.2013704317 -2.088639970 -1.474642669  0.612224444  0.97337528  5.828500e-01
q3_2  -0.254792497  0.4476396999 -1.867095848 -0.819081547  0.429024117  0.86702888 -4.828014e-01
q3_3  -0.180238385  0.4298248819 -0.005719385  0.010742603  0.779848024  0.49592929 -1.555691e-01
```

Is it correct for these loadings to be larger than $\pm$1?

When I run a regular factor analysis using `fa()` from the `Psych` package I always get loadings values <1.0. I'm trying to calculate MCA loadings that are somewhat comparable in range, but I'm not sure why the value ranges differ so much

Comment: I can't speak specifically of `FactoMineR` being not an R user. But here is my comment. In correspondence analysis tradition we typically don't use term "loading". What corresponds directly to it there is called "coordinates under principal normalization by inertia": please read [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141755/3277), especially "Weighted biplot" section. These values are, like loadings, equal to eigenvector elements multiplied by sq. root of the respective eigenvalue.

Comment: (cont.) If you divide the result by the sq. root of the category (point's) scale (inertia), you get the rescaled "loading" which you seek. The rescaled "loading" squared is known in CA as _contribution of dimension to point_ which is often available in a package's output. We encounter analogous rescaled loading in PCA ([see](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/119758/3277), [see](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/102999/3277)). It ranges between -1 to 1.

Comment: As a side note, instead of `sweep(mca_fit$var$coord,2,sqrt(mca_fit$eig[1:ncol(mca_fit$var$coord),1]),FUN="/")` , you can use: `mca_fit$svd$V`