# Why do I need Loadings when I can reconstruct data with eigenvectors in PCA?

Tags: time-series, pca, eigenvalues

I have read the responses to this question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143905/loadings-vs-eigenvectors-in-pca-when-to-use-one-or-another), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94048/pca-and-exploratory-factor-analysis-on-the-same-dataset-differences-and-similar/94104#94104) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102882/steps-done-in-factor-analysis-compared-to-steps-done-in-pca/102999#102999), but I am still confused on the application of *loadings* and *eigenvectors*.

Principally this statement (from the first link),

> It is loadings which "restore" the original covariance/correlation matrix (see also this thread discussing nuances of PCA and FA in that respect);

I am performing PCA analysis on a historical time series of interest rates. The steps I followed are:

1. Given a data series $\bf{X}$, compute a centered data series $\bf{X'}$.
2. Compute a correlation matrix on the centered data $\bf{C}$.
3. Perform a decomposition of the correlation matrix to determine eigenvectors $\bf{v}$ and eigenvalues $\bf{\lambda}$.
4. The *principal components* (also known as *PC scores*?) are then calculated as $\bf{P=X' \cdot v}$. The first three components have high explanatory power (explaining > 95% of the variance).
5. The first three eigenvectors $\bf{v'}$ and components $\bf{P'}$ are retained and the reconstructed data $\bf{R}$ is computed as:
   $$
   \bf{R = [P' \cdot v'] \cdot \sigma(X) + \mu(X)}
   $$

The reconstructed data from step 5 is exactly as I would have expected it.

I have not used the loadings $\bf{L}$ (defined as $\bf{L} = \bf{v} \cdot \sqrt{\bf{\lambda}}$). So I'm still struggling to understand their significance given I am able to reduce and reproduce the original data.

Observations on the calculations,

1. The eigenvectors $\bf{v}$ are **unit scaled** ($\bf{\Sigma v^2 = 1}$).
2. The mean of the principal components $\bf{\mu(P) = 0}$.
3. The standard deviation of the principal components $\bf{\sigma(P) = \sqrt{\lambda}}$.

So perhaps I am getting confused because of this last point, namely the standard deviation of the principal components is not equal to $1.0$, but is rather the square root of the eigenvalue.

But it's not clear to me how one would get a centered principal component. I'd appreciate if someone could explain where one would use loadings instead of eigenvectors.