# What does the Psi term in factor analysis signify?

Tags: factor-analysis

> Diagonal elements of Psi (...)
>    represent independent noise variances
>    for each of the variables
>
> C.M. Bishop, *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*

...but I'm not clear on what does the Psi signify.
I've applied FA to a series of images, received Psi matrix and now struggling with interpreting the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following Bishop's notation, the FA model is written as (Eq. 12.64, p. 584):

$$
p(x|z)=\mathcal{N}(x|\mathbf{W}z+\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\psi})
$$

where $\boldsymbol{\psi}$ is a $D\times D$ diagonal matrix of so-called variable uniquenesses, that is the variance not accounted for by the latent factors, whereas $\mathbf{W}$ reflects factor loadings $\lambda_i$, that is the correlation of variable $i$ with factors represented in $z$ (more exactly, the square of $\lambda_i$ is the variance explained by the latent factor).

If you're not familiar with the FA literature, I would suggest "lighter" approach, e.g. William Revelle has good tutorials on his website [personality-project.org](http://www.personality-project.org); especially, I would suggest Chapter 6 of his forthcoming book on Psychometric methods entitled [Constructs, Components, and Factor models](http://personality-project.org/r/book/Chapter6.pdf). You will shortly understand the relations between PCA and FA. Specifically, with PCA, we are constructing linear combinations of observed variables (this yields a composite variable), whereas in FA we are expressing each variable as a weighted combination of hypothesized latent factors (where weights are called loadings) plus an error term (the $\boldsymbol{\psi}$ in the above formula). In sum, the FA model incorporates a model for noise--this is what is expressed in Equation 12.65; but see [What are the differences between Factor Analysis and Principal Component Analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-are-the-differences-between-factor-analysis-and-principal-component-analysis), for additional discussion.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bishop's notation, but IIRC, the loading $\lambda_{ij}$ in matrix $W$ equals the correlation of observed variable $i$ with latent factor $j$ only in the orthogonal-factor model. In a model with correlated factors, matrix $W \cdot C_f$ contains the variable-factor correlations if $C_f$ is the correlation matrix of the factors (not equal to the identity matrix).

Comment: @caracal (+1) Good point. Yes, Bishop considers an orthogonal solution.