# How to organise an iterative manual rotation of n component pairs?

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis, rotation, reproducible-research

I am currently building a `q.rotate()` function for the [qmethod](https://github.com/aiorazabala/qmethod) R package for [Q Methodology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_methodology).

As is desirable for Q, I'd like users to be able to iteratively rotate any given component pair loadings from a principal components analysis (PCA).

Like so (early draft):

[image: first draft of q.rotate() interface]

Crucially, users should be able to go back to *already* rotated pairs, and continue rotating them.

This is giving me some headaches, because [rotations don't commute](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162031/does-the-order-of-rotations-matter-in-rotating-pca-loadings-by-hand#comment308180_162031), so the **order** in which rotations are done matters.

This is **not a technical question** on how to implement this in R.

I am wondering **how to organise this** from a statistical procedure.

I don't know whether what I'm planning makes any sense.

Let's say I have three retained components: `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, and this is their (unrotated) loadings matrix:

```
# suppose I have some ORIGINAL loadings matrix, from a principal components analysis, with three retained components
loa.orig <- cbind(c(0.6101496, 0.7114088, 0.3356003, 0.7318809, 0.5980133, 0.4102817, 0.7059148, 0.6080662, 0.5089014, 0.587025, 0.6166816, 0.6728603, 0.7482675, 0.5409658, 0.6415472, 0.3655053, 0.6313868), c(-0.205317, 0.3273207, 0.7551585, -0.1981179, -0.423377, -0.07281187, -0.04180098, 0.5003459, -0.504371, 0.1942334, -0.3285095, 0.5221494, 0.1850734, -0.2993066, -0.08715662, -0.02191772, -0.2002428), c(-0.4692407, 0.1581682, -0.04574932, -0.1189175, 0.2449018, -0.5283772, 0.02826476, 0.1703277, 0.2305158, 0.2135566, -0.2783354, -0.05187637, -0.104919, 0.5054129, -0.2403471, 0.5380329, -0.07999642))
```

Here's a draft order of things for the iteration:

1. User chooses a component pair *from the combinations of factors* one of columns from `combs <- combn(x = ncol(loa.orig), m = 2, simplify = TRUE)`
2. User enters an angle in degrees to rotate *the given factor pair*, say `f1` vs `f2`, say `5°` clockwise.
3. `f1` and `f2` are rotated `5°` clockwise
4. *all* plots involving either  `f1` or `f2` are updated, because they all change. (**correct**?)
5. User enters *another* angle to try out, say `10°`, still on `f1` and `f2`
6. repeat steps `3`, `4`, `5` as long as the user wants
7. user indicates that she is done with `f1` and `f2`.
8. the rotated loadings matrix is saved to, say `loa.rot`
9. return to step `1`, now all rotations, say between `f2` and `f3` are done *on the rotated*  `loa.rot` from the past loop.
10. repeat steps `1-9`.
11. once user indicates that she is done with *all* factor pairs, last `loa.rot` is returned.

Does that make sense?

---

**PS**:

There is an additional problem.
Obviously, I'd like for this procedure to be *reproducible*, preferably without saving all the steps the user took.
(They may be redundant).
Instead, to create a reproducible *"recipe"*  for this by-hand rotation, I would take the final `loa.rot` and compute the *simplest* step of rotations required to arrive at the final `loa.rot` from the initial `loa.orig`.
No idea yet how to do that, that's [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491228/how-do-i-find-the-angles-between-an-original-and-a-rotated-pca-loadings-matrix).

Comment: This sounds like a question on user interface, not on statistics.

Comment: Regarding your question on stackoverflow, the answer is simple: you should store the final rotation matrix of all components (3 in this case), i.e. 3x3 rotation matrix. You sequence of planar rotations can always be combined together in such a matrix.

Comment: apologies if this is off-topic @amoeba; I hoped to ask less about interface, but about whether this sequence makes sense from a statistical procedure, and whether this would be a meaningful interaction with the data.

Comment: thanks for the pointer; I am out of my wits, obviously. 
The 3x3 rotation matrix should look like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5341489/rotmatrix.png), correct? Do I then add or multiply the other rotation pairs?

Comment: That's right, it's how 3x3 rotation matrix looks like when the rotation happens around one of the coordinate axes (3rd one in this case). What you need to do is to multiply these matrices for all your "simple" rotations.