Doubts About PCA: Why Are Loadings Often Overlooked?
I have an existential doubt regarding PCA. I’ve often seen it used in genetics, where you work with groups of genes that you might not fully understand in terms of their function. In such cases, PCA is used to capture latent variability in the dataset and generate new, uncorrelated variables (principal components).
However, when PCA is applied to datasets with known, tangible variables—especially when the goal is to reduce dimensionality or visualize outliers—I've noticed that there’s rarely a follow-up analysis of the loadings of these variables. In my particular case, I work with tangible variables, and I’m often interested in understanding how they relate to one another and the weight they carry within the components. Yet, in most studies, I only find the percentages of explained variance, and that’s it.
This leaves me wondering: Why isn’t there more emphasis on interpreting the loadings? Are the loadings not important for understanding how the original variables behave and contribute to the principal components? To me, the loadings seem critical for interpreting the relationships among variables and for identifying their influence on variability. Am I missing something, or is this just an underexplored area in PCA?
Edit (07/12):
Thank you, Peter Flom and Nick Cox, for your valuable contributions to the thread. I will focus on your questions
In my specific case, @Nick Cox, I worked with a set of 12 genes, aiming to identify potential clusters and understand which genes accounted for the greatest variability. My project focused on three different nutrient combinations and their impact on gene expression (Image 1). While dimensionality reduction is helpful for simplifying the data, I’m also exploring whether components can be associated with biological functions. For instance, cholesterol efflux-related genes appear to contribute predominantly to PC1, while glucose metabolism might be linked to PC2. Please note that this is speculative and not intended for strict conclusions—my goal is to explore whether loadings can provide insights into these associations and contribute to hypothesis generation.
Given this objective, I’m particularly interested in the loadings, as they reflect each gene’s contribution to the principal components. By analyzing the loadings, I hope to identify which genes most significantly contribute to the variability captured by the components. These insights could support or refine some of the hypotheses underlying my research.

In this context, some genes strongly influence Dim1, positively contributing to the variance captured by cholesterol-related processes (as seen in Image 2). This is because certain genes clustered along Dim1 are associated with these functions. While this observation helps me better understand gene behavior, I acknowledge that it’s a simplistic approach with several limitations. Therefore, this serves as an exploratory tool rather than a basis for drawing definitive conclusions.

The loadings associated with these results are as follows:

Regarding bibliography I support on:
Principal Component Analysis, Second Edition. I.T. Jolliffe
Exploratory Multivariate Analysis by Example Using R
@Peter Flom, you’re absolutely right that loadings are not necessarily needed if the main focus is simply on identifying outliers or explaining variance. However, the purpose of this thread was specifically to delve into the topic of loadings. Since I was asked about my intentions with them, I shared my particular doubts.
In my case, my objective goes beyond merely visualizing outliers—I’m also interested in identifying patterns or clusters. In this context, I assumed that loadings could play a useful role. However, after exploring other examples here on StatsExchange, I’ve noticed that loadings are not typically the central focus of PCA discussions. Despite this, I still feel that loadings might be particularly important for my analysis.
Am I overlooking something here?
Could it be that my uncertainty stems from a lack of understanding of the geometric interpretation of loadings? Perhaps a clearer geometrical perspective could help me better conceptualize and utilize these results. What are your thoughts?
Thank you in advance for your unestimable contribution

I agree that it is often relevant to look at the loadings, and some people actually do that. You may think it doesn't happen enough, and that's fair enough. I don't see a big general problem there though. Maybe some people need a reviewer who tells them to do it, but that may be more or less it.

For geometric interpretation of loadings, please look here https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/119746/3277

I disagree in part with @Peter Flom, but the prior question is indeed what you are trying to do with a PCA?
Generally, which literature are you looking at? is a simple but fundamental question, as tribal habits and what is expected or acceptable in a thesis or paper can vary remarkably from one field to another.
If PCA application is merely an exercise in calculating PCs so that you can focus on a subset as giving fewer summary variables but capturing much of the variability, then what the PCs mean may be of secondary importance or even quite irrelevant. For example, a plot of PC2 scores versus PC1 scores can be helpful in showing how far there is discernible cluster structure or a continuum of variation. Whether the PCs can be given an interpretation is another question.
If I do PCA myself I certainly want to look at the loadings and indeed I prefer to calculate correlations between the PCs and the original variables. What do the PCs mean? is for me a key question. However, these PCAs of mine rarely see public light, as either they are disappointing, or their interpretation is already familiar, or they indicate indirectly how to deal better with the original variables.
If PCA is an attempt to discover or uncover latent variables, then that is a different goal. And for every practitioner who wants to argue there for factor analysis or structural equation modelling, there is another practitioner who wouldn't touch those methods, although the reasons vary from person to person.
In fields I know most about -- various Earth and environmental sciences -- I never see factor analysis papers any more. It was killed off some decades ago by various poor experiences and devastating critical reactions. I gather that is not at all the case in some behavioural and social sciences, where enthusiasm for factor analysis continues.
EDIT in response to further details
Disclaimer: I can tell the difference between Mendel and Mendelssohn and between gene and meme, but otherwise my knowledge of modern biology is negligible.
I prefer to work with correlations not loadings if only because I can relate correlations to the interval $[-1, 1]$.
I find biplots a bit oversold and in any case often hard to read.
I prefer this representation of the output you show. The graphs just show loadings in different order.


In essence PC1 looks like a roughaverage across variables and the loadings don't vary much. In contrast PC2 contrasts some genes compared with some others.
As above, I can't help with interpretation.
I will add a perhaps obvious note that listing in alphabetical order by gene name isn't itself clearly informative -- unless that is how the names are constructed.

Thank you for the answer. I was also thinking about the reasoning  that variables that cluster together and point in similar directions likely share similar relationships with the principal components and may reflect similar biological functions or processes. I am not sure if this statement is merely speculative or really means something but I am sure I've read elsewhere

As everyone likes to point out, correlation is not causation. Oddly, back in the day, Karl Pearson saw this as a feature, not a problem. The popularity of this dictum owes much to assonance (in English, at least).

I think this gets at the difference between PCA and factor analysis. In PCA, the goal is dimensionality reduction while losing as little as possible. It's not really the meaning of the components. That's more a factor analysis goal, where we try to recover latent factors. In FA, we do pay attention to the loadings - that's a big part of figuring out what the latent factors mean.
As you say "especially when the goal is to reduce dimensionality or visualize outliers" well.... when those are the goals, the loadings are not important.
