# How to interpret this loadings statement in PCA given the example in R?

Tags: r, pca

I am reading in the fabulous book of "Exploratory Multivariate Analysis by Example Using R" 2nd edition by Husson, however when I came across this sentence about PCA loadings and their calculation I couldn't get its math or how to prove it in R code:

> Loadings are interpreted as the coefficients of the linear combination
> of the initial variables from which the principal components are
> constructed. From a numerical point of view, the loadings are equal to
> the coordinates of the variables divided by the square root of the
> eigenvalue associated with the component.

How can loadings be calculated given the above statement in this R example from the variables divided by the square root of the eigenvalue of the principal component?

I know that each principal component is a linear combination of the variables and loadings are the coefficients of these linear combinations.
**Example**

```
A <- as.matrix(data.frame(mtcars[,c(1:7,10,11)]), nrow = 9, byrow = TRUE)
S <- scale(A)
pca_svd <- svd(S)

pca_svd$v # here is the loading matrix
        [,1]    [,2]    [,3]     [,4]   [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]    [,9]
 [1,] -0.393  0.0275 -0.2212 -0.00613 -0.321  0.7202 -0.3814 -0.1247  0.1149
 [2,]  0.403  0.0157 -0.2523  0.04070  0.117  0.2243 -0.1589  0.8103  0.1627
 [3,]  0.397 -0.0889 -0.0783  0.33949 -0.487 -0.0197 -0.1823 -0.0642 -0.6619
 [4,]  0.367  0.2694 -0.0172  0.06830 -0.295  0.3539  0.6962 -0.1657  0.2518
 [5,] -0.312  0.3417  0.1500  0.84566  0.162 -0.0154  0.0477  0.1351  0.0381
 [6,]  0.373 -0.1719  0.4537  0.19126 -0.187 -0.0838 -0.4278 -0.1984  0.5692
 [7,] -0.224 -0.4840  0.6281 -0.03033 -0.148  0.2575  0.2762  0.3561 -0.1687
 [8,] -0.209  0.5508  0.2066 -0.28238 -0.562 -0.3230 -0.0856  0.3164  0.0472
 [9,]  0.245  0.4843  0.4641 -0.21449  0.400  0.3571 -0.2060 -0.1083 -0.3205

pca_svd$d # here are the eigenvalues
[1] 13.241  8.034  3.954  2.866  2.383  1.959  1.805  1.347  0.829

sqrt(pca_svd$d) # the square root of the eigenvalues
[1] 3.639 2.834 1.988 1.693 1.544 1.400 1.343 1.161 0.911
```

So the `A` matrix has 32 rows and 9 columns (variables), so what is meant by variable coordinates and what does this statement really mean?

**Update: using FactoMineR package**

When I use the `FactoMineR` package which the above book deals with, I even get more confused as the meaning of the statement in question, see the code below:

```
library(FactoMineR)
res.pca <- FactoMineR::PCA(mtcars[, c(1:11)], ncp = 9, quali.sup = c(8, 9))

head(res.pca$var$coord) # here store are the coordinates of the variables 
R> head(res.pca$var$coord)
      Dim.1   Dim.2   Dim.3    Dim.4   Dim.5    Dim.6   Dim.7   Dim.8    Dim.9
mpg  -0.935  0.0397 -0.1571 -0.00315  0.1373  0.25338  0.1236 -0.0302  0.01712
cyl   0.957  0.0227 -0.1792  0.02095 -0.0501  0.07893  0.0515  0.1960  0.02423
disp  0.945 -0.1283 -0.0556  0.17477  0.2083 -0.00692  0.0591 -0.0155 -0.09860
hp    0.873  0.3888 -0.0122  0.03516  0.1261  0.12453 -0.2257 -0.0401  0.03751
drat -0.742  0.4930  0.1065  0.43535 -0.0693 -0.00541 -0.0155  0.0327  0.00567
wt    0.888 -0.2481  0.3222  0.09846  0.0802 -0.02947  0.1387 -0.0480  0.08479

# actually these are the loadings (V . Sigma) as proof to that: 
res.pca$svd$V %*% diag(res.pca$svd$vs) == res.pca$var$coord # TRUE
```

So how can we compute loadings according to the statement in question of FactoMineR book and package from the variable coordinates when the coordinates themselves are actually the loadings matrix as we know it ($V \cdot \Sigma$)?

Accordingly, my guess is that this statement could read like the following:

> Loadings are interpreted as the coefficients of the linear combination
> of the initial variables from which the principal components are
> constructed. From a numerical point of view, the loadings are equal to
> the coordinates of the variables <s>divided</s> which are the eigenvectors scaled up by the square root of the eigenvalue associated with the component.

Comment: I believe you should rather be using the `FactoMineR` package (which is what the authors use) to understand the above statement: `FactoMineR::PCA` doesn't return the loadings but the coordinates of the variables on each PC. Usually, [we say](https://is.gd/SX2byr) that the eigenvector times the square root of the eigenvalue gives the component loadings which can be interpreted as the correlation of each item with the principal component. More information in this [great post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/104640/930) by @amoeba.

Comment: On loadings and eigenvectors of PCA https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/143905/3277

Comment: @chl, I added the FactoMineR package code as requested, but the statement gets more confusing by the word divided by, what could be the better wording for that then?

Comment: @ttnphns, I am aware of that excellent post on this confusion between the two, and how prcomp() output `$rotation` refers to loadings when they are actually eigenvectors (direction only devoid of magnitude reflected by the variance). But would you agree with the statement made by the author? If not, how would you re-phrase it correctly? –

Comment: I believe the confusion comes from the fact that the authors of the `FactoMineR` package use terminology related to PCA "à la française" (French school of data analysis), according to which factorial coordinates reflect correlations between variables and factor axis (or components).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering only to the citation at the beginning of the question. I did not consider the analysis in R provided in the question.

I admit that the author of the first passage may have made some confusion in terminology. Let us define properly.

$v$ is the eigenvector's values. It is the eigenvector from eigencecomposition of the covariance matrix of the variables or, equivalently, the right eigenvector from SVD decomposition of the data matrix. Eigenvector values are the standardized coordinates of the variables as vectors in the space of the principal components, i.e. on a biplot or loading plot - see last paragraph [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/143949/3277).)

$\lambda$ is the corresponding eigenvalue (the component's variance).

$a=v \sqrt{\lambda}$ is the loading vector. [Loadings](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/143905/3277) $a$ are the coefficients of the linear combination predicting a variable by unit-scaled principal components. $V_i= a_{i1}F_1+a_{i2}F_2...$.

While the coefficients of the linear combination to compute *unit-scaled* principal component values (scores), $F_j= b_{1j}V_1+b_{2j}V_2...$, are given by

$b=a/\lambda=\frac{v\sqrt{\lambda}}{\lambda}=v/\sqrt{\lambda}$

(see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/126985/3277), "Computation of **B** in PCA: ... When component loadings are extracted but not rotated (...) amounts to simply dividing each column of **A** by the respective eigenvalue - the component's variance").

So you have eigenvector divided by the square root of the corresponding eigenvalue. The original citation was:

> Loadings are interpreted as the coefficients of the linear combination
> of the initial variables from which the principal components are
> constructed. ... the loadings are equal to
> the coordinates of the variables divided by the square root of the
> eigenvalue associated with the component.

Then, if my interpretation is correct, that passage should sound like:

> Component score coefficients are the coefficients of the linear
> combination of the initial variables from which the principal
> components [component scores] are constructed. ... the coefficients are
> equal to the coordinates of the variables [the eigenvectors] divided
> by the square root of the eigenvalue associated with the component.

**In this case**, the author seems to mean component score coefficients by the term "loadings".

This is so **if** by "coordinates of the variables" the author meant *eigenvectors* (standardized = normalized = unit-scaled coordinates of the variables) and implied the components themselves to be *unit-scaled* (as we often think in factor analysis context).

But **if** by "coordinates of the variables" the author meant *loadings* (variance-scaled or full-scaled coordinates of the variables) and implied the components themselves to be *variance-scaled* or full-scaled (as we often think in PCA context), then we are in the situation of tautology:

Since $a=v \sqrt{\lambda}$, then $v=a/ \sqrt{\lambda}$,

and also we know that then eigenvector values *are* the coefficients $b$ to compute the *full-scaled* principal components from the input variables. If that is what the author meant, then the passage should sound like:

> Eigenvectors are the component score coefficients, the coefficients of the linear
> combination of the initial variables from which the principal
> components [component scores] are constructed. ... the coefficients are
> equal to the coordinates of the variables [the loadings] divided
> by the square root of the eigenvalue associated with the component.

**In this case**, the author seems to mean eigenvector entries by the term "loadings".

---

I might recommend to read the paragraph "Digression" in my [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/288646/3277) about the similarities and differences between PCA and Factor analysis.

Comment: from the above R analysis, by numbers I would confirm that per `FactoMineR` package, the `output$var$coord` means *loadings* (variance-scaled or full-scaled coordinates of the variables) then according to your second premise we are in the situation of tautalogy...

Comment: can I say that the $B$ matrix would be the change of basis matrix that would transform my newly obtained data in the experiment to the newly projected PCA space spanned by the first plane for example of PC1 and PC2? So $B$ is $V$ when $XV$= $U \Sigma$ = PC scores.

Comment: Yes, correct. PC scores (unstandardized, i.e. with their native variance) are computed directly by eigenvectors, so B=V then.