# Visualizing and interpreting principal components

Tags: data-visualization, pca, matlab, interpretation

I have performed principal component analysis (PCA) in Matlab via

`[U,S,V] = svd(X)`

Now I have to show the principal directions of the considered principal components; either by finding a way to plot them or interpret them in terms of the features.

If I have chosen 6 of the 12 PCs, I am still not able to plot them. So how can I interpret them in terms of the features?

Comment: You will most likely have to plot each PC to an other one, such as (1,2), (1,3), (1,4) ... (2,3), (2,4) etc. How much  inertia do those 6 PC gather? Ploting them is the easiest way, otherwise, you'd have to look at each coordinates for each point, and see where the maxima and the minima are (within the [-1, 1] range)

Comment: Try the functions `pca` & `biplot`.

Comment: +1 to both comments above. Is there a particular reason you chose six instead of, say, three PCs? The "feature vectors" are the PCs. You might want to use your PC scores to cluster/visualise your sample more effectively.

Comment: Also, please note that we have a lot of useful questions and answers about PCA here. Your questions suggest that you did not really explore the existing answers. In this case, looking at threads tagged with [pca] and [data-visualization] might be helpful for you here. For example, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7860.