# How to interpret ggbiplot() visualization of PCA in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, pca, biplot

To apply and visualize PCA in R often ggbiplot() is used. What is the meaning of this plot ? Why  it is useful for PCA ?

We can consider this example: https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/11/28/computing-and-visualizing-pca-in-r/

[image: Figure]

In particular, what is the meaning of arrows and circle?

Comment: Thanks for comments. I have seen the posts. I have understood that arrows are linked to correlation: more correlated are two variables and more collinear are the arrows. It is true? And what is the precise relation?

Comment: And what about the white circle? Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: You may also want to read [Positioning the arrows on a PCA biplot](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/141085/).

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Comment: Regarding the white circle, see "Visualizing a million" thread: "The white circle indicates the theoretical maximum extent of the arrows."

Comment: I have read this comment in the old question but there is a problem: what is the length of arrows? I think is the projection of the original variables on the subspace generated by pc1 and pc2 but i'm not sure

Comment: The author of the ggbiplot package is the same user who posted the answer in the "Visualizing a million" question. Please see this old comment exchange: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7860/visualizing-a-million-pca-edition#comment253864_7862 (last three comments). The details of how the circle+arrows are scaled are not very clear to me, and he never replied.

Comment: Ok. If I understand more I will write here!