# What to do when EFA requires more factors but the number of variables is low?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

There's a lot of information on the forum about the differences between principal components analysis (PCA) and exploratory factor analysis (EFA) (for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-are-the-differences-between-factor-analysis-and-principal-component-analysi) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123063/is-there-any-good-reason-to-use-pca-instead-of-efa)). I am new to both methods, but after looking through various answers to previous posts, I think that EFA is a better fit for my question, but I don't think it fits my data.

I have 6 observed variables which purport to measure the same construct. I want to contrast these 6 observed variables to hypothesis on whether they measure the same thing or if, in fact, they could be reflecting different constructs. This is very exploratory at this stage; I'm not interested in testing a hypothesis, but rather on coming up with one.

My first thought was to run a PCA and show how the variables cluster together in a biplot. However, I think most people would agree EFA is better for my question(?). The problem with EFA in my case is that 2 factors is the maximum I can choose to extract (as my number of observed variables is 6) and the EFA result indicates that I need more than 2 factors (I'm using the factanal function in R).

- Could I simply use PCA and justify this on the grounds that more variables would be needed for a reliable EFA? (Note that I wouldn't be able to have many more variables as there aren't other ways of estimating the construct - this isn't an issue with the amount of data.)
- If EFA is the only way to go, what could be done regarding the need for more factors vs. low number of variables?