# In max-variance PCA, why is the variance of the projected data equals to $\sum_{j=1}^M\mathbf{u}^T_j\mathbf{S}\mathbf{u}_j$?

Tags: pca

In my machine learning course we have been taught that given a new axis $\mathbf{u}_j$ and a datapoint $\mathbf{x}_n$, the projection is $z_j = \mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{x}_n$. The variance of $z_j$ can be thus proved to be $\mathbf{u}_j^T\mathbf{S}\mathbf{u}_j=\lambda_j$. So far so good.

But then my professor said that "the variance of the projected data" is:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^M\mathbf{u}_j^T\mathbf{S}\mathbf{u}_j=\sum_{j=1}^M\lambda_j
$$

I fail to understand why the variance of the projected data is the sum of the variance in each new axis. Shouldn't the variance be a matrix? Like $diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_M)$?

**In max-variance PCA, why is the variance of the projected data equals to $\sum_{j=1}^M\mathbf{u}^T_j\mathbf{S}\mathbf{u}_j$?**

Comment: The covariance Matrix of the projected data-vector $(z_1,...z_n)$is indeed $diag(\lambda_1,...\lambda)$ as you suggest. But what he refers to is the variance of $z_1+...z_n$, which is the sum of the individual variances of the $z_i$ as they are uncorrlated. This can be seen as measuring the total variance of your data.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22571/3277