# how to find percentage of total variation from population covariance matrix and population mean matrix

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix, population

I have a matrix with dimension nxp. No:of observations are not known. But no: of variables is 3. So p=3. 
Population mean is defined as µ1=1,µ2=-1,µ3=2.

$\sum$=

\begin{bmatrix} 1 & k & 0\\ k & 1 & k\\ 0 & k & 1\end{bmatrix}
How to find the value of k such that the principal components PC1 and PC2 account for more than some percentage (say 75%) of total variation of X?

Comment: It looks like Sigma is a correlation matrix not a covariance matrix because of the ones on the diagonal. Could you precise what is X ?

Comment: X = (X1, X2, X3) distributed as N3(µ, Σ). I did determinant( Σ - lamda * I ) = 0. To get value of k in terms of lamda.

Comment: When you say "they account ..."  what would you mean exactly ? The two first eigenvectors ? Please edit your question to give more details.

Comment: Yes..There was mistake in question. I edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the cumulative ratio of variance explained is equal to the sum of the reduced eigenvalues (see [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22571/116857) for details), you have to

- calculate the three eigenvalues of your matrix in function of k
- reduce and sum the two first eigenvalues
- find the value of k that gives you the needed percentage (ie : 0.75)

Comment: I think we have to find all the eigenvalues of the matrix to find sum of the reduced eigenvalues. (λ1+λ2) / (λ1+λ2+λ3)

Comment: I didn't mentionned it but you are right ! Answer edited.