# Average correlation

Tags: correlation, pca, multivariate-analysis

In this blog post
[Extraction of features from a given correlation matrix](https://marti.ai/qfin/2020/08/14/correlation-matrix-features.html)

the author claims:

> the percentage of variance explained by the first PCA component and the average (absolute) correlation is the same thing

I think I understand what it means "variance explained", i.e. [PCA and proportion of variance explained](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22569/pca-and-proportion-of-variance-explained)
.

I can not understand how the proportion of highest eigenvalue and the average correlation provide the same information.

Comment: I can find a sense in which the statement is true for $2\times 2$ correlation matrices, but not for larger ones.  Here is `R` code to test it (showing my interpretation of the quotation, too).  Here, `n` is the dimension of a random correlation matrix: `n <- 30;
X <- cor(matrix(rnorm(n^2), n));
c(\`Mean absolute correlation\`=mean(abs(X)), \`Largest eigenvalue\`=max(eigen(X)$values) / n)`