# Is it correct to calculate the covariance matrix on scaled features?

Tags: variance, pca, covariance, feature-scaling

I have a set of features with the following covariance matrix:

```
           feature_1   feature_2   feature_3
feature_1  3347        -57         -17
feature_2  -57         2           0.4
feature_3  -17         0.4         53
```

Each feature is on different scale, thats why the variances magnitude differ that much.

Now, the total "variability" is 3347 + 2.4 + 53 = 3402

According to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22569/pca-and-proportion-of-variance-explained/22571#22571) can I say that "`feature_1` explains 98% (3347 / 3402) of the total variability" ?

I think this would be unfair, because that feature has that big of a variance only because its scale.

So my question is, would it make more sense to first scale the data (using e.g. the [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)) before calculating the covariance matrix ?

Comment: You misunderstood the part about total variability, that's only about PCA

Comment: But the total variability at that post, is the same both during the PCA and before (in the covariance matrix in the original features), right ? Or do you mean, because the covariances are not 0 ?