# Is it valid to use only some of the components as regressors from a PCA?

Tags: regression, pca

I was trying a 4 components PCA where the 1st and 2nd components have emerged exactly as I expected, but the other two components do not commensurate with the theory. I mean, I expected a little different kind of loads. Some of the variables expected to belong to component 3 have actually loaded highly on component 4 and some expected to belong to component 4 have loaded on component 3. I have tried in different ways, but things don't really improve and theoretically component 3 and component 4 do not make much sense to me. You can have a view of the loadings table here-

[image]

Now, I am planning to use the 1st and 2nd components as regressors (as they have clearly emerged) along with the 9 individual variables that have loaded highly on the other two components (because their linear combinations don't hold to be meaningful) in a further regression on a dependent variable. My questions are-

1) Is it statistically valid to use only component 1 and 2 (component scores, basically) along with the 9 individual variables of component 3 and 4 as regressors in a regression?

2) Is it possible to include a few other variables as regressors too which were not included in the PCA?

Comment: Are your predictors measured subjectively?  If so, you'll want to read http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-are-the-differences-between-factor-analysis-and-principal-component-analysi

Comment: Thanks @rolando2. I think I have made a mistake here. What I used is basically method of principal components of factor extraction in FA. I wanted to avoid distributional assumption of maximum likelihood method. Now, is this legal to use the factor scores of the first two factors along with some of the measured variables not loaded highly on these first two factors individually in a further regression as regressors?

Answer (score 3):

This is a complicated question.  First of all, when you are interested in interpreting your components in meaningful ways, you should be aware that principle components analysis is only useful for telling you how many factors to extract from your data.  Generally, after a PCA, you plot the variances of the components in order from largest to smallest.

There are a wide variety of ways of making the decision as to how many factors to extract (see, for example, [Zwick & Velicer, 1986](http://psycnet.apa.org/?fa=main.doiLanding&doi=10.1037/0033-2909.99.3.432)).  One of the easiest and most widely used is the "scree test", a graphical approach in which you plot the size of the variances of each of your components in descending order.  You then identify the "elbow" of the plot, or the place in the plot where the size of the components tapers off dramatically, and where the remaining components account for approximately equal amounts of variance.  So, in the plot below, we would identify the third component as the elbow and choose to extract two components.

[image: Screeplot]

Once you have made a decision about how many components to extract, you should choose how to rotate your components (so that you know which items load on each extracted factor).  In general, rotations that allow your extracted factors to correlate (such as the oblimin rotation) result in more interpretable solutions than rotations that do not (such as the varimax).  After all, how often does it occur that two extracted factors are exactly orthogonal (which is enforced in varimax or other orthogonal rotations).

Overall, though, I would bear in mind that the process of Exploratory Factor Analysis (i.e., deciding how many factors to extract through PCA, choosing a rotation, interpreting your resultant factors and factor loadings) is an iterative process (may I say **exploratory**) process; if a given solution is uninterpretable, it can be perfectly valid to choose to extract a different number of factors to see if that yields a solution that is more interpretable.  Exploratory Factor Analysis is **NOT** Confirmatory Factor Analysis, nor should it be treated as such; you are not testing the adequacy of a given measurement model using some test of significance.  Instead, you are attempting to pull structure out of a set of data in such a way that the structure has a valid theoretical interpretation.  In the end, the final criterion by which you should judge your EFA is interpretability, rather than some metric of model fit.

Comment: Thank you. My data contained mixed types of variables, binary, nominal, ordinal and scale, all. So, I went for CATPCA first. The scree plot suggested me a 4 factor solution. But as CATPCA can not rotate the factors, so I used the optimally scaled variables in Analyze > Factor Analysis > Method(Principal Component) > Rotation(Varimax). I have tried different rotations too to get more clear factors. But not getting a better result! Now, as I mentioned, I want to use the two linear combinations and some other variables individually in a further regression. Will that be valid?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of your factor analysis?  Are you trying to establish that certain variables fall into conceptual clusters and groups so that you can use these clusters as predictors in later analyses?

Comment: Yes, besides those clusters of variables there are some other variables too that are not conceptually included into the clusters. I need to run them all on a DV.

Comment: Well the validity of your PCA (and subsequent analyses) really depends on whether you're interested in the subsequent interpretation of your factors.  If you are, then I would continue to diagnose why you have an uninterpretable solution (are some of your variables uncorrelated, did you use the right rotation, etc).  If you're purely interested in prediction (you don't care about interpretation), then I would say that your approach is valid.