# What are the differences between these two kinds of PCA?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, svd, matrix-decomposition

The book "Elements of Statistical Learning" describes Principal Components Analysis through SVD as follows:

$$X = UDV^T$$

Then $ UD $ are the Principal Components and $ V $ are the directions.

However, later in the book, in section 14.7.1 "Latent Variables and Factor Analysis" the authors write:

$$ S = \sqrt{N}U $$

$$ A^T = DV^T/\sqrt{N} $$

$$ X = SA^T $$

Then:

$$ X_p = a_{p1}S_1 + ... + a_{pp}S_p $$

Questions:

1. What can be done with the second one that can't be done with the first one?
2. Is the first one for a "tall" matrix and the second one for a "wide" matrix? So then does the matrix as used in the first one need to be transposed before it is used in the second one?
3. Why does the second one have $\sqrt{N}$ ?
4. Any other mathematical differences that I have missed?
5. If my matrix is set of functions/curves, what is the difference between having $V$ as the curves and $S$ as the curves?
6. Is there any advantage to using full SVD over reduced SVD?
7. It seems like the first is takes $UD$ and $V$ and the second one takes $U$ and $DV'$. Does it actually matter which one we take as long as the matrix is transpose accordingly?

Comment: Maybe you will find this link helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-are-the-differences-between-factor-analysis-and-principal-component-analysi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems to be not about "two types" of PCA. The second "type" is a continuation of the explanation of the "first": the concept of *loadings* and how to get them, is introduced this time. Loadings are more important in factor analysis than in PCA because they are the source of interpretation of the latents (in PCA, you not often interpret the components).

Those formulas you cite from section 14.7.1 is about *one of the ways* to compute the  *loadings* $A$ (which are actually eigenvectors normalized by the corresponding eigenvalues) in PCA, and then to restore the original data $X$ via them.

As I've said, computationally there exist several equivalent ways to do PCA. Some are based on eigen-decomposition, some are on SVD. Your formulas demonstrate one of the SVD-based paths.

I'll show the equivalence of a more "classic" approach and "your book's" approach. Because variances and covariances are customarily computed on *df*=N-1 (rather then N) I will change $N$ in your formulas to $N-1$.

```
X (N=10, P=5). Columns (variables) are already centered
    .8585    .0568   1.2111   1.1736    .3553 
  -1.2951    .9300    .0384   -.1677   -.9702 
  -1.0160   1.2390    .1478   1.0005  -1.1788 
   -.4922   -.1105  -1.0723   -.4102   -.5783 
  -1.1354    .9282   -.2975  -2.2278   -.1559 
    .8969  -1.0482    .4764   -.1490   1.9451 
   1.7236   -.7944    .1691    .3063   -.0586 
   -.6571   -.6302    .8333   -.3861    .5726 
    .5776   -.4670   -.6474    .0858   1.5036 
    .5391   -.1038   -.8589    .7746  -1.4349
```

Do PCA via eigen-decomposition of the covariance matrix

```
COV 
   1.0899   -.6261    .1155    .4505    .5092 
   -.6261    .6259   -.0708   -.0929   -.5922 
    .1155   -.0708    .5373    .1782    .2820 
    .4505   -.0929    .1782    .9345   -.1696 
    .5092   -.5922    .2820   -.1696   1.2500 

Eigen-decompose it as COV = V * L * V'
Eigenvalues are the diagonal of L
   2.2551 
   1.2374 
    .6092 
    .2132 
    .1227 
Eigenvectors V
    .6005    .3243   -.3643    .4278    .4675 
   -.4661    .0595    .2700   -.0756    .8370 
    .1768    .0323    .8109    .5447   -.1162 
    .1848    .7802    .2696   -.5262   -.0870 
    .5973   -.5306    .2535   -.4875    .2445 

Loadings A = V * sqrt(L).
    .9017    .3607   -.2843   -.1976    .1637 
   -.7000    .0662    .2108    .0349    .2932 
    .2655    .0360    .6329   -.2515   -.0407 
    .2775    .8679    .2104    .2430   -.0305 
    .8970   -.5902    .1978    .2251    .0856 

Scaled (standardized) principal component values ZC = X * inv(A') [while Raw PC values not shown here are C = X * V]
    .7540    .9422   1.3979   -.5022    .8363 
  -1.2085    .0184    .5931    .0914   -.1545 
  -1.1192   1.0383   1.0192    .8653    .4843 
   -.5693   -.1925  -1.2520    .6248   -.8670 
  -1.1133  -1.7783   -.2782  -1.1484   1.2461 
   1.4954   -.8130    .2940    .3194   -.0711 
    .9700    .7077   -.8169  -1.6394    .2291 
    .2113   -.7449   1.0070   -.3127  -2.1638 
    .9083   -.5324   -.5858   1.8373    .8981 
   -.3287   1.3543  -1.3783   -.1356   -.4376

Data are restored as X = ZC * A'
    .8585    .0568   1.2111   1.1736    .3553 
  -1.2951    .9300    .0384   -.1677   -.9702 
  -1.0160   1.2390    .1478   1.0005  -1.1788 
   -.4922   -.1105  -1.0723   -.4102   -.5783 
  -1.1354    .9282   -.2975  -2.2278   -.1559 
    .8969  -1.0482    .4764   -.1490   1.9451 
   1.7236   -.7944    .1691    .3063   -.0586 
   -.6571   -.6302    .8333   -.3861    .5726 
    .5776   -.4670   -.6474    .0858   1.5036 
    .5391   -.1038   -.8589    .7746  -1.4349
```

Do PCA via "your" path of SVD decomposition

```
Singular-value-decompose X as X = U * D * V'
U 
   -.2513   -.3141    .4660    .1674   -.2788   -.1197   -.4790    .4706   -.1616   -.1549 
    .4028   -.0061    .1977   -.0305    .0515    .4986   -.2315    .0909    .6514   -.2454 
    .3731   -.3461    .3397   -.2884   -.1614    .1885    .5965    .1991   -.2917    .0163 
    .1898    .0642   -.4173   -.2083    .2890    .0567   -.1659    .3104   -.3984   -.6107 
    .3711    .5928   -.0927    .3828   -.4154    .0371    .0318    .3563   -.1429    .1830 
   -.4985    .2710    .0980   -.1065    .0237    .7576   -.0050   -.0022   -.2693    .1004 
   -.3233   -.2359   -.2723    .5465   -.0764    .1195    .4867    .1960    .2385   -.3387 
   -.0704    .2483    .3357    .1042    .7213   -.1719    .1959    .4296    .0961    .1671 
   -.3028    .1775   -.1953   -.6124   -.2994   -.1808    .1295    .4201    .3829    .0370 
    .1096   -.4514   -.4594    .0452    .1459    .2155   -.2015    .3284    .0000    .5958 
D 
   4.5051    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000 
    .0000   3.3371    .0000    .0000    .0000 
    .0000    .0000   2.3416    .0000    .0000 
    .0000    .0000    .0000   1.3853    .0000 
    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000   1.0507 
    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000 
    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000 
    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000 
    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000 
    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000 
V (these right eigenvectors are what we had in eigendecomposition)
   -.6005   -.3243   -.3643    .4278   -.4675 
    .4661   -.0595    .2700   -.0756   -.8370 
   -.1768   -.0323    .8109    .5447    .1162 
   -.1848   -.7802    .2696   -.5262    .0870 
   -.5973    .5306    .2535   -.4875   -.2445 

Now do what your "section 14.7.1" suggests.
S = U * sqrt(N-1)
   -.7540   -.9422   1.3979    .5022   -.8363   -.3592  -1.4369   1.4118   -.4849   -.4647 
   1.2085   -.0184    .5931   -.0914    .1545   1.4958   -.6945    .2727   1.9543   -.7361 
   1.1192  -1.0383   1.0192   -.8653   -.4843    .5655   1.7896    .5973   -.8751    .0489 
    .5693    .1925  -1.2520   -.6248    .8670    .1701   -.4977    .9312  -1.1951  -1.8322 
   1.1133   1.7783   -.2782   1.1484  -1.2461    .1114    .0953   1.0690   -.4288    .5490 
  -1.4954    .8130    .2940   -.3194    .0711   2.2728   -.0149   -.0067   -.8079    .3011 
   -.9700   -.7077   -.8169   1.6394   -.2291    .3584   1.4601    .5881    .7156  -1.0162 
   -.2113    .7449   1.0070    .3127   2.1638   -.5157    .5877   1.2888    .2882    .5013 
   -.9083    .5324   -.5858  -1.8373   -.8981   -.5425    .3886   1.2604   1.1488    .1109 
    .3287  -1.3543  -1.3783    .1356    .4376    .6465   -.6044    .9851    .0001   1.7873 

A' = D * V' /sqrt(N-1)
A (note that the non-empty part are the Loadings)
   -.9017   -.3607   -.2843    .1976   -.1637    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000 
    .7000   -.0662    .2108   -.0349   -.2932    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000 
   -.2655   -.0360    .6329    .2515    .0407    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000 
   -.2775   -.8679    .2104   -.2430    .0305    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000 
   -.8970    .5902    .1978   -.2251   -.0856    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000    .0000 

Data are restored as X = S * A'
    .8585    .0568   1.2111   1.1736    .3553 
  -1.2951    .9300    .0384   -.1677   -.9702 
  -1.0160   1.2390    .1478   1.0005  -1.1788 
   -.4922   -.1105  -1.0723   -.4102   -.5783 
  -1.1354    .9282   -.2975  -2.2278   -.1559 
    .8969  -1.0482    .4764   -.1490   1.9451 
   1.7236   -.7944    .1691    .3063   -.0586 
   -.6571   -.6302    .8333   -.3861    .5726 
    .5776   -.4670   -.6474    .0858   1.5036 
    .5391   -.1038   -.8589    .7746  -1.4349
```

So, once again, it is all about different ways to program/implement PCA. I don't know if the approach you cite has any advantage (e.g. faster or numerically more stable?). One potential disadvantage though is that it deals with large matrices $U$ and $S$ and produces void cells in $A$.

Comment: Thank you. R's svd package has some fast algos for SVD. From another project that I worked on, it was faster to use the SVD algos than the eigendecomposition with the QR algo in R/LAPACK

Comment: I have been using the reduced SVD instead of the full SVD. So my U has been 5*5.

Comment: What are the extra columns in a full SVD for?

Comment: Of course you can reduce "extra columns" that won't change the result. I just wanted to say that the book itself doesn't say anything about that important trick.