# Are there two types of Principal Component Analyses?

Tags: variance, pca, factor-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

At first, I learned that PCA is a different type of analysis than factor analysis: PCA is only used for data reduction and factor analysis is used for detecting latent variables that underlie observed variables. So, my take for that PCA is that it is a very different type of stats analysis than EFA.

When I read pieces of literature on exploratory factor analysis (e.g., https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/seminars/introduction-to-factor-analysis/a-practical-introduction-to-factor-analysis/ ), they always specify that there are two types of EFA: one called "principal component analysis", and the other called "common factor analysis". The difference between the two is that the PCA used total variance that includes both common variance and unique variance for factoring, while common factor analysis only uses common variance for factoring. However, according to this, PCA is considered as a type of EFA according to these pieces of literature.

Now, here is my question: are the PCA I described in the above two paragraphs the same thing? Or are there actually two PCAs, with one being a totally different analysis from EFA, one being just a subtype of EFA?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between Factor Analysis and Principal Component Analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-are-the-differences-between-factor-analysis-and-principal-component-analysi)

Comment: The confusion arises from people defining Factor analysis differently. With a narrow definition of factor analysis PCA is excluded, but taking a broader one includes PCA.

Comment: No, there is one PCA. PCA is often seen as a simplest and not genuine FA. The narrow sense or bona fide FA is the common factor analysis. Here on this site, we have a large number of discussions about similarities and differences between the two. Search "PCA factor analysis".