# Naming PCA factors: is it a minor art?

Tags: pca, interpretation

**What is a good, structured and reproducible method to name selected components or factors in principal component analysis (PCA)?** Clearly, the sign and magnitude of the entries in the eigenvectors are key, but how do you go from there to a qualitative, solid descriptor or name?

---

**BACKGROUND** (skip unless interested in soccer):
It turns out that you (meaning, 'I') barely make it through getting a shaky understanding of dimensionality reduction in data with correlated variables; fight your way through the linear algebra to understand (on a good day) the change in coordinates, the rotation of the data cloud and other arcane concepts, in great measure thanks to herculean didactic efforts directed to grandmothers, and other family members ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2691/67822)). Finally, the `R` code also falls in place (`princomp` v `prcomp`), and you are ready to select the main factors or components among the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix. You get the output of the `summary`, generate a `biplot` and you are done, hoping that somebody smarter can get through the shock of overlapping info on the `biplot`, and squeeze some meaningful information that can be, yes, explained to your mother, grandmother or to your son. But you can't just print the `biplot` - you are at the dinner table...

So what to do? **How to give meaningful name to `PC1` and `PC2`**? Do they need a name? They should have a name, because just going though the components in the corresponding eigenvectors doesn't seem like a great, impacting way of getting a paper published. So **what are the guidelines or principles to assign these names**?

[Here](http://www.economist.com/blogs/gametheory/2014/09/analysing-football-styles)'s an example for soccer fans with kids with questions. You get the *Economist*, and finally understand what makes tiki-taka the best soccer ever played. That is if you know that `ABCB` means (from watching the games) that the ball goes from Busquets to Xavi, from Xavi to Iniesta, and from Iniesta back to Xavi, for example. And that in `ABAC` the `A` may be Messi looking for a wall before giving an assistance for goal. `ABAB` stands for two soccer geniuses hugging the ball while the defenders give up in frustration. So now (sorry baseball and football fans) "Principal Component 1" in the opening plot makes a lot of sense. But what happens if you are not a Barça fan... you are then at the mercy of the explanation of "Principal Component 1": "*a much greater propensity to play `ABAC` and `ABCB` passing sequences, as well as `ABAB`*". And because it's the Economist, there is some further explaining. But still... this was the first time I ever heard of PCA, and couldn't get faster to Wikipedia. Shouldn't there be an effort made to name this component or factor something that sounds like a new *meta*-variable - something like, "*back-and-forth passing*" (not great, I know)?

The same thing tends to happen in other instances in which after the mathematical effort is carried out, the assignment of qualitative descriptors or names to the PC's is not compelling. **Without nice definitions (or ideally, names) for the principal components, it is difficult to grasp what they mean, and how they are a weighted linear composition of the initial variables**.

Here's a plot in an otherwise phenomenal post on-line (I will hold off on crediting it because of what follows) at the end of a PCA on different models of cars in the year 2004 - basically data on technical specs, price, etc:

[image]

Very hard, isn't it, to go for any cars other than luxury German models?

Comment: PCs are just some derived variables, the axes/directions in the multidimensional space of the data. If I give you an arbitrary scatterplot of some data poins where all the points are labeled but the axes are not labeled - will you have difficulty inventing the missing labels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You focus on "naming", but I would say that the real problem is *understanding* what principal components mean. You are right: this is an art. It often turns out that they are very difficult to interpret, hence all the attempts  (especially in factor analysis literature and practice) to rotate the components/factors in order to achieve "simple structure", i.e. structure that will be easier to interpret (see [my answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160422/)).

I don't know where you took your figure from, but this dataset was nicely analyzed in [Cosma Shalizi's lecture notes on PCA](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/350/lectures/10/lecture-10.pdf), and I quote from page 7:

> This [matrix of eigenvectors] says that all the variables
>   except
>   the gas-mileages have a negative projection
>   on  to  the  first  component.   This  means  that  there  is  a  negative  correlation
>   between  mileage  and  everything  else.   The  first  principal  component  tells  us
>   about whether we are getting a big, expensive gas-guzzling car with a powerful
>   engine, or whether we are getting a small, cheap, fuel-efficient car with a wimpy
>   engine.
>
> The  second  component  is  a  little  more  interesting.   Engine  size  and  gas
>   mileage hardly project on to it at all.  Instead we have a contrast between the
>   physical size of the car (positive projection) and the price and horsepower.  Basically, this axis separates mini-vans, trucks and SUVs (big, not so expensive, not
>   so much horse-power) from sports-cars (small, expensive, lots of horse-power).

Once you understood that, you can look for good names.

Comment: Ah, okay. Apologies if you did not want to reveal Cosma's analysis to other readers. What's a "qplot" by the way? What you inserted in your post is called a "biplot".

Comment: Yes. I did read the description on the plot, and the article helped me a lot, which is why I was hesitant to quote it, given that the plot (replicated using R after downloading the data) was attempted to make the point that sometimes PCA, from the lack of good summarizing names to the busy biplots, leaves amateurs / beginners like myself between fascinated and speechless. Thank you for taking the post seriously. It stemmed from my difficulties in trying to reconcile the math with the ultimate results, and sifting though papers looking for nice legends to the plots

Comment: biplot - I don't know where 'qplot' came from. [Here](https://github.com/RInterested/PCA/blob/master/CAR%20MODELS%202004) is the code I used. Thank, again!

Comment: Good answer, but I would go further: It is an art that is very often bound to fail. There is no guarantee whatsoever that principal components can be meaningfully interpreted (except maybe for the first one). The reason is that interpretations depend on model assumptions, but PCA is a procedure that is not based on a model – unless you happen to have a model where the data is a linear combination of uncorrelated signals with orthogonal distribution across original measurements, which is rare.

Comment: @A.Donda: "interpretations depend on model assumptions" - I don't follow. Why would I need to have a model or to make any assumptions when interpreting a principal component? - aren't I just *describing* a linear combination of the original variables?

Comment: @Scortchi, well, maybe one could distinguish between a priori and post hoc descriptions. If you're looking for a certain structure in your data, formulate this as a model, and then find a good fit, you can be reasonably certain that this fitted structure has a meaning. If you just perform some procedure, and then later on try and attach a meaning to something you found, you can get lucky or you can't.

Comment: Let's say there are some interpretable variables underlying the data you compute a PCA on. They may happen to be uncorrelated signals with orthogonal distributions, and they may happen to be picked up as PCs, and then you've gotten lucky. More likely they do not have such properties or are not picked up properly, and you will end up with mixtures of the true signals which have no clear meaning.

Comment: So to be more precise: "interpretations are strongly supported by model assumptions", and if you don't have a model you very likely end up with something uninterpretable.

Comment: @A.Donda: Thanks. I think you're using "interpretation" in a somewhat stronger sense than I am - to do with drawing conclusions about latent features of a population. Take Shalizi's car data: I've no idea what population, if any, these might be supposed to be representative of - perhaps someone just picked out some cars they liked. So I'm not concerned at all about picking up signals, or probability distributions; but "size vs. fuel economy" & "sporty vs. boxy" still seem like good descriptions of the first two PCs.